# capture cmd output in a batch file

Tags: batch-file, cmd

i need to capture the output of a batch file (maintenance.bat) that will run on a schedule to restart services and run some maintenance. i need to see the output of the bat file.

my bat file calls other bat files. here is an example

```
pushd d:\workingdirectory
call servicecontroller.bat services.stop
call rotatelogs.bat
call pushconfigupdates.bat
popd
```

i need to capture the output of all the commands ran.

Thanks

Answer (score 3):

try with

```
myfile.bat > log.txt
```

For more info you can check [here](http://www.microsoft.com/resources/documentation/windows/xp/all/proddocs/en-us/redirection.mspx?mfr=true).

Comment: with `myfile.bat > log.txt 2>&1` you'll be able also to capture the error stream